# 14.04 Software updater problem

Tags: updates

Running 14.04 and the Software updater keeps giving this message:
Package operation failed.
The installation or removal of a software package failed.
I tried updating via the terminal and received same message.
Any ideas anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Install 'synaptic package manager' in the repository(software center).

Open Synaptic

Click 'custom filters' on the bottom left

Select 'broken'

Highlight all broken packages and mark for complete removal.

Let me know if this helps!

You can also try the following:

Open terminal

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

If neither of those options resolve the issue, I would install bleachbit and clean up your system.

Get the latest version here:

http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux

After installing bleachbit open terminal

```
sudo bleachbit
```

The program will start

Under APT select all options

Under DEEP SCAN select all options except thumbs.db

Under SYSTEM select all options except free disk space and trash

Click 'preview' and then click 'delete'

If none of the above works you can try the following:

Open terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ntrack-module-libnl-0 --reinstall
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already had 'synaptic package manager' installed, however im not sure which directory its in. I Opened Synaptic Clicked 'custom filters' on the bottom left
and Selected 'broken', and received 0 packages broken. ???

Comment: sorry. what's a super key?

Comment: super key is the windows key

Comment: Thanks again. tried the terminal and seems to download/update most packages, but ended with this error message; W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: you can remove those repositories manually using YPPA Manager! :)  And its all fixed!

Comment: will try bleachbit.

Comment: You don't need bleach bit!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Comment: Tim, I already got it fixed for him...bleachbit is AWESOME!